# Clutch problems in 5th gear

Tags: transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, diesel

I'm having strange problem. While I drive my car in 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th gear, everything is fine and dandy. However, when I change my gear to 5th. Car runs perfectly BUT the clutch becomes so easy to push, its like pushing nothing. At the very end (2 inch) i can feel some resistance, as if it's the clutch. Moment occurs right after I shift and it takes the problem about 1-2 minutes to become to this stage. The problem is usually followed by problem with downshifting when as if the gears won't let go. When I downshift and start driving (for instance in city), the problem becomes less worse, but not the point where I can't tell if it happened or not. When I let the car shut down and come next morning, it's ok. Any ideas?   (Car Škoda Octavia II 1.9 TDI PD 77kw)

Answer (score 1):

Sure sounds like you are having issues with a hydraulic clutch setup. Clutch appears to be working in an erratic fashion. Could be a problem with the slave cylinder, or the master cylinder. Does this car have a hydraulic clutch and have you checked the fluid level lately? One or both of the cylinders could be leaking internally or externally allowing the clutch to perform in this manner. Would certainly be the first place to look for something wrong. Possibly the hydraulic system simply has air in it and needs to be bled.